# PHP - Echo All Results From MySQL SELECT Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that executes a MySQL SELECT query, and I would like to echo each row from that query to the page. I have tried multiple methods to go about doing this, but none seems to work. The most reasonable of these ways that I have come up with is provided below, but it doesn't work either.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT count FROM countTable;") or trigger_error($conn->error);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);
$count = sizeof($row);
for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
{
    echo $row[$i];
}
```

The code provided above only prints the first row resulting form the query. How can I modify this code so that it prints the entirething?

Comment: @RobertRozas Code has been edited to include the SQL query.

Comment: `fetch_array()` only get 1 row - `Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array returned from fetch_array is the set of columns from one row of results. Your query has only one column (ie: "count"), so the size of the array will always be 1. Calling fetch_array multiple times will return each row one at a time.

What you want is something like:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH)) {
   echo $row[0];
}
```

*Note, I haven't run this, so there might be some small syntax error I've overlooked.

Comment: When I first tried your code, it only printed the second row. Just out of curiosity, I added a third row to the table, and now it prints out the second and third rows. It continues to omit the first. I'm working on a potential solution.

Comment: Do you have a $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH) line above the while loop? If so, it's fetching the first row in advance of the while loop.

Comment: Yes, that's what the problem was. I'm a PHP noob, so I make noob mistakes. I can't vote your answer up, but if I could I would. I'm afraid the green check-mark is the best I can give you.

Comment: No worries. I was on here to ask a golang noob question myself and thought I'd poke around and see if there was anything I could answer while at it. Cheers.

Comment: I ♥ StackOverflow, but the problem is that the questions that are open to be answered are way to hard for me to even begin to comprehend, and the ones that I do understand are already answered.